# CSS doesn't load on one of my route/view

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

[image]

I have a `sub-view` that extend my `master-view`, and for some reasons all my css doesn't seem to load **only** on that page. I extend them as usual like I normally do.

---

**view** `show.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.internal.master')
@section('content')

TESTING ... 

@stop
```

I notice, it only break on that route : `/account/112`

---

Any hints / suggestion on this will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without seeing your file paths or how you are loading your CSS, it's very difficult for us to say but it sounds like your file paths are wrong.

There is a difference between these two:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

Note the forward slash.

The first one is relative to your current path. So, for example, if you're currently at `http://localhost:8000/account/112`, the first one is like saying `http://localhost:8000/account/css/app.css`, which is most likely unwanted behavior. The second one is relative to the root directory so it will always be `http://localhost:8000/css/app.css`, which is probably what you want to do.

Laravel also comes with helpers function like `asset` so if you decide to use that and do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

It will generate an absolute URL / full path from your root URL. So, it'll generate something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css">
```

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: It works by adding a slash in front of my css `<link href="/css/style.default.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, the {{ asset ('path') }} did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

`/account`  and `/account/112` can not access same path in same way. Like if `/account` access a image like  'images/img/img.jpg' , `/account/112` need to access it like '../images/img/img.jpg'. Its all about folder structure. Now for your problem you need to use `asset` like below (laravel 5 specific)

```
// if you have save css file at as root/public/css/main.css
{!! HTML::style('css/app.css') !!}
```

remember to add to composer.json

```
 "illuminate/html": "5.*"
```

And to aliases

```
 'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
 'HTML'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class
```

**Point to be noted:**

```
    {{asset('css/some.css')}}
```

this is for laravel4. you wont get it working in laravel 5.