# bootstrap styling doesn't work in some views in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

I'm begginer in Laravel 5.2, I make a simple personal blog and here's views folder

[image: Views Folder]

in home.blade.php I extends 'layouts.master' which uses bootstrap and works great.
now I made a new route to show specific blog:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'post'], function(){
    Route::get('{id}', function(){
        return view('blog');
    });
});
```

when I go to http://localhost:8000/post/1 it works great but the problem when I extend layouts.master bootstrap and my custom css doesn't work !
it works in home.blade.php and works in pages/about.blade.php correctly but when I try to make any new route to a view and extend layouts.master it extends but bootstrap and custom css doesn't work.
[image: blog view]

Have any idea why is that?
Notice: my css and bootstrap is in public folder.

Comment: Can you show us how you are including bootstrap inside your master layout?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that this is a relative vs absolute URL. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377408/css-doesnt-load-on-one-of-my-route-view#answer-33377661

Comment: <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
Here's how I included my css

Answer (score 9):

@ThomasKim Is absolutely right. The path to your bootstrap file is relative. So when you're on `localhost:8000` it can correctly traverse to `css/bootstrap.min.css`.

However when you're on `/post/1` then the URL request for the css file changes to:

```
localhost:8000/post/1/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

And we know that's incorrect. To resolve this, use an absolute path by prepending a `/`.

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This will ensure that it always attempts to traverse the file from public/css/bootstrap.min.css. `public` is omitted in the URL structure, but that is where all HTTP requests resolve to.

**UPDATE**

It would actually be best to use Laravel's `asset` or `secure_asset` functions to resolve these assets instead:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min/css') }} rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The `asset` helper will resolve directly from `/public`

Note that `asset` will use the `schema` of the page request to resolve the dependency, whereas `secure_asset` will force the dependency over `https` no matter what the schema of the request is.

Comment: To add to this, it looks like the fonts that are being used are missing a protocol, so they'll attempt to resolve to localhost:8000/post/1/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/.... They need to be prepended with http:// or https://.

Comment: Great ! I add / to css and js paths and it finally worked correctly !!!
Thanks a lot buddy :)

Answer (score 6):

To make life super easy, use Laravel's asset() helper:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/stylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Yes, it provides the exact same thing as referencing it as simply "/css/..." but I find it to be good practice, especially when things get a bit more advanced later down the line.

Answer (score 4):

You must have used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
```

in your main blade layout template, that why facing this problem

Use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css">
```

and this will resolve the issue.

Just append a forward slash `/` before css file path, which indicates the public directory of your project.